# How to use mmap in c

Tags: c, mmap

I've search and I can't seem to find a way on how to use mmap. This is what I have..

```
char *pchFile;
if ((pchFile = (char *) mmap (NULL, fileSize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (char *) -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Mmap Err: \n");
    exit (1);
}
```

So, how do I from obtaining pchFile, read from the file? Is pchFile, the array of bytes mapped from mmap? How do I read at an offset like for say 400 bytes? Can I have an offset and read only a certain amount e.g only read 100 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pchFile` is just a plain old `char *` (with `fileSize` valid bytes accessible). So if you want a pointer to the data at an offset of 400 bytes, you can just use `&pchFile[400]` or `pchFile + 400` for implicit or explicit pointer arithmetic.

How you limit it to 100 bytes is based on the API you're using; C itself has no concept of the "length" of a pointer (there are APIs for NUL-terminated strings, but raw file data isn't likely to have NULs in useful places). For `memcpy`/`memcmp` and friends, you'd pass `&pchFile[400]` as the source, and pass the size as `100`. For initializing a C++ `vector`, you'd pass the start and end pointers to the constructor, e.g. `std::vector<char> myvec(&pchFile[400], &pchFile[500]);`, etc. Usually, it'll either be a start pointer and a length, or a start and end pointer.